# ASP.NET ToolkitScriptManager removes teleric scripts in RELEASE mode

Tags: asp.net, telerik, bundling-and-minification, scriptmanager

My site is based on ASP.NET WebForms and I use Telerik.Web.UI controls.
I added bundling for the whole site (.NET Web.optimization). And when I turned on bundling scripts which must be generated for Telerik were missed.
Seems like all scripts for Telerik are inserted into my `ScriptManager` which I have on master page.

```
<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/BlogService.svc" InlineScript="False" />
    </Services>
</cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

I understand that if I do not have `debug ="true"` in my web.config my `ScriptManager` will be also in Release mode.

So I turned on debug mode for my `ScriptManager` manually. And it helped me - scripts for Telerik controls appeared on site. But also there were a lot of scripts which I want to be in Release mode.

```
<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1" ScriptMode="Debug">
```

1) Why do telerik scripts go to this script manager? I tried to find usages of my `ScriptManager` but there weren't any usages.
I want this `ScriptManager` to be in Release mode but I also need scripts for Telerik.

2) Why were the Telerik scripts removed?

3) Can I create a new `ScriptManager` only for Telerik, set its mode to Debug, and use my first `ScriptManager` in Release mode? How can i configure it?

Answer (score 0):

Scripts for MS AJAX based controls are added by each control (during its server initialization) to the script manager (this is why a script manager exists). Telerik controls are no exception.

A common problem is encountered with AjaxControlToolkit and Telerik, however: http://www.telerik.com/forums/telerik-ui-for-asp-net-ajax-and-ajax-control-toolkit. **Try the latest ACT release**, however, as they have promised it contains fixes for these issues where they broke MS AJAX: https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27831 (see the `Sys$Component$_setProperties` function).